# Closing JFrame that opened a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog, formclosing

Basically I have a JFrame that opens a JDialog.

The problem I'm facing is when I attempt to do a right click on the taskbar -> close window in Windows OS

The JDialog would be 'blocking' the closing event.

I would want to close the application even if the JDialog is shown but at the same time blocking any input into the parent frame.

Edit: As a norm, dialog boxes are made to block the output but as I have mention in the comment below :

> Problem lies when users need to close the application but when with a
>   few dialog box on screen. It requires them to close all to them before
>   being able to close the entire application. It would be better if only
>   selected critical dialog boxes blocks the closing event but not those
>   trivial ones

Main class

```
public class Main  {
private Frame frmMain;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Main();
}

public Main(){
    initialize stuff..
    frmMain.setVisible(true);
    Message msg = MessageFrame.openDialog(frmMain);
    ...
}
```

MessageFrame class

```
public class MessageFrame extends JDialog {

private Message message;
public static void openDialog(Frame frame){
     return new MessageFrame(frame).message;
}

private MessageFrame(Frame frame){
    super(frame);
    setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    ...
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: *"I would want to close the application even if the JDialog is shown but at the same time blocking any input into the parent frame."*  Whereas *the rest of us* would prefer an app. that works in a consistent manner to the other apps. on our computers..  I hope for the sake of your users that you either a) change that requirement, or.. b) fail to achieve it.

Comment: Problem lies when users need to close the application but when with a few dialog box on screen, it requires them to close all to them before being able to close the entire application. It would be better if only selected critical dialog boxes blocks the closing event but not those trivial ones.

Comment: *"It would be better if.."* ..the user attended to those dialogs.  Dismissing them if need be.

Comment: If a dialog does not need to be made simply remove the creation of it from the program, unless this would impact the running and intention of the program.  Dialogs are made for a reason not on whim.